# How can I check if the integer value of a string is less than something in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
        var topRole = 25;

        var menuItems = _contentRepository.GetPk()
            .Where(m => m.Status <= topRole)
            .OrderBy(m => m.Order)
            .Select(m => new MenuItem
```

Status has values of "00", "05" or "10"

Is there some way I can convert m.Status to an integer and then compare to see if it is less than or equal to topRole?

Comment: When I try this I am getting an error 'int' does not contain a definition for 'parse'

Comment: It does contain a definition for `Parse` with capital P. `System.Int32.Parse(m.Status)` should be equivalent to `int.Parse(m.Status)`. See [Parse at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var menuItems = _contentRepository.GetPk()
        .Where(m => int.Parse(m.Status) <= topRole)
        .OrderBy(m => m.Order)
        .Select(m => new MenuItem);
```

If this query is for LINQ to SQL, you may need to use `Convert.ToInt32` instead:

```
var menuItems = _contentRepository.GetPk()
        .Where(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Status) <= topRole)
        .OrderBy(m => m.Order)
        .Select(m => new MenuItem);
```

Comment: int.Parse() is not supported by linq to Sql. Conver.ToInt32() may work though.

Comment: @ValBakhtin Good point - I believe most EF providers support Int32.Parse - but Convert will work too

Answer (score 3):

use `int.Parse(m.Status)`

```
var menuItems = _contentRepository.GetPk()
            .Where(m => int.Parse(m.Status) <= topRole)
            .OrderBy(m => m.Order)
            .Select(m => new MenuItem)
```

EDIT: changed "parse" to "Parse".

Comment: I get an error "'int' does not contain a definition for 'parse'"